# Compound Interest Calculation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

In __________ years a sum will double at $5\%$ per annum compound interest.

Options given are:

a. 15 years 3 months

b. 14 years 2 months

c. 14 years 3 months

d. 15 years 2 months

The way to solve is  as below:
\begin{align*}
A & = P[1+(r/100)]^n\\
2P & = P [1+(5/100)]^n\\
2 & = [1+(5/100)]^n\\
\log 2 & = n \cdot \log(1.05)\\
0.3010 & = n \cdot 0.02118
\end{align*}

Therefore $n = 14.2069$ years $= 14$ years and $(0.2069 \cdot 12)$ months $= 14$ years and $2.48$ months.

Now the question is whether $2.48$ months should be rounded to $2$ months or $3$ months?

**This is a academic question where I need to choose from the 4 options as given above. The book says answer is 14 years 2 months, but conceptually, before 2.48 months, the money does not double, so answer needs to be 14 years 3 months. Just asked this on forum to get to know if I am missing something.**

Comment: It depends on how the interest is evaluated. If you get the interest only once a year, then the result should be 15 years, before you don't have enough money there.

Comment: Please see this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.  You can see how I formatted your work by right-clicking on the equations, then selecting Show Math As TeX Commands.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: Thanks for your guidance in formatting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't make much sense, if the interest is evaluated only once a year. Clearly, after 14 years you would only have $1.05^{14}=1.9799\ldots$ times the initial amount and only after 15 years you will have twice the initial amount (and a little bit more).

I think there is an error in the book, unless it is understood that the interest is evaluated continuously, but then anyway none of the options would be correct.

The $\ln 2/\ln (1.05)\simeq 14.206\ldots$ is just the "average" in the following sense: in the long run, the initial amount will be at least $2^n$ times the initial amount after $\lceil n\times (\ln2/\ln (1.05))\rceil$ years, where $\lceil x \rceil$ is the smallest integer larger than $x$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I agree with you.

Comment: No problem. Welcome to the math site, by the way :)